# How to link a button to specific page

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I'm trying to link a button as seen below to my login page. My login page is located in Areas > Identity > Account > Login.cshtml. How can i link my button to this login page with asp?

Previously I linked my button using `asp-controller` and `asp-action` but this scaffolded login page does not have a controller or action that I know of.

```
    <div>
       <a style="background-color: #193C8D" class="btn btn-primary">Go to login.</a>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use ASP.NET Core it can be done like this:

```
<a style="background-color: #193C8D" class="btn btn-primary" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login">Go to Login</a>
```

Please let me know if it helps. Because I don't know which version of ASP.NET you are using. Here you can find a few examples: [Anchor Tag Helper in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: This is not working. I am using .NET CORE 3.1. Here's the url to the page if that helps: http://localhost:63718/Identity/Account/Login

Comment: @A.Vandijck Check again, please. I've made the changes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the anchor you need:

```
<a style="background-color: #193C8D" class="btn btn-primary" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login">Go to Logins</a>
```

Compared to MVC, it is quite messy when using tag helpers with razor pages, but it gets the job done.